# How to install WebSharper 2.5alpha using VS 2013 RC?

Tags: websharper

I wanted to install the WebSharper 2.5.48 alpha into VS 2013. The Nuget package did load but the vsix file failed with an error indicating there was no product it could extend. Inspecting the manifest showed VS 11 as the highest version supported. I hacked the manifest file adding VS 12 Pro as an option. The install then proceeded but subsequently failed with the following errors. Any ideas?

```
10/5/2013 1:51:11 PM - The following target products have been selected...
10/5/2013 1:51:11 PM -  Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013 RC
10/5/2013 1:51:11 PM - 
10/5/2013 1:51:11 PM - Beginning to install extension to Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013 RC...
10/5/2013 1:51:11 PM - Install Error : Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.MissingReferencesException: This extension cannot be installed because the following references are missing:
- NuGet Package Manager
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.CheckForInstallBlockers(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, Boolean isNestedExtension, Boolean& olderVersionInstalled)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.InstallInternal(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, Boolean perMachine, Boolean isNestedExtension, IDictionary2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, AsyncOperation asyncOp, UInt64 totalBytesToWrite, UInt64& totalBytesWritten)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.BeginInstall(IInstallableExtension installableExtension, Boolean perMachine, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionManagerService.InstallWorker(IInstallableExtension extension, Boolean perMachine, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
```

Comment: Please see https://bitbucket.org/IntelliFactory/websharper/issue/166/alpha-build-vsix-and-vs-2013-rc